# Regression with autocorrelation given by a graph

Tags: regression, networks

Supppose I would like to fit a standard regression model of the form $y = \alpha + X \beta + \epsilon$, but my observations come from a networked population (eg. social network). I have the graph $G$ representing connections between observations and it's reasonable to assume that errors will be autocorrelated between connected observations.

How can I get valid standard errors of the $\beta$'s ?

Comment: post your data ........

Comment: I don't have any data which I could share. I don't really see what would it bring. I think the setup is quite easy to imagine: just an ordinary table with accompanying graph representing links betwen observations from the table. Alternatively, you can think of it as an attributed graph with each vertex $v_i$ of the graph having a vector $x_i$ and a scalar $y_i$ as attibutes. It's a question which came to my mind while I was working on one of the projects at my work.